# Making Bootstrap's navbar appearing in different position on desktop/mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make Bootstrap's navbar appear at the top on desktop view and at the bottom on mobile view. It is possible? How can I do it?

There is my actual HTML for top navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; GitUp</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; Selección de idioma</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <code><span class="fa fa-code"></span></code> por Federico Damián <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="https://feskyde.github.io"><span class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; <strike>Mi casa</strike></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Contacto</li>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/feskyde"><span class="fa fa-github fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; GitHub</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/feskyde"><span class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://facebook.com/fedeedamianschonborn2"><span class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/116581300175876868268"><span class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; Google+</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Mis proyectos</li>
            <li><a href="https://feskyde.github.io/gitup"><span class="fa fa-cloud-upload fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; GitUp</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://feskyde.github.io/ashblock"><span class="fa fa-shield fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; A Shell Blocker</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://feskyde.github.io/rosespine"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; RoseSpine</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://feskyde.github.io/kawaiicode"><span class="fa fa-code fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; KawaiiCode</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Otros</li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com"><span class="fa fa-file-code-o fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; Bootstrap</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/"><span class="fa fa-fort-awesome fa-fw"></span>&nbsp; Font Awesome</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take off the navbar-fixed-top class and add your own css

```
.navbar-inverse {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .navbar-inverse{bottom: 0; top:auto;}
}
```

Then at max width 767px screens your navbar will be fixed on the bottom.

Comment: No problem you may also want to add top:auto to the media query css I will edit the answer to show that.  Don't forget to check it as the right answer if you can.